# Ubuntu not showing its self on BIOS System

Tags: bios

I have lenovo T420 i5-2nd gen machine. I have install ubuntu in it rufus in it and get the usb bootable but when i booted the system it doesn't show me the ubuntu on booting.... I have tried lots of time tried different methods to get ubuntu on bios.

Watched lots of videos on youtube and tried different methods but it didn't work.
Kindly resolve the issue as I got really frustrated to solve such kinds of problem.

Comment: My guess is the ISO wasn't validate (ie. was flawed because of a bad download & you didn't verify it), or your write to media failed, so I'll provide https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016

Comment: Is system BIOS(CSM) or UEFI? And then what mode do you have for booting flash drive. Rufus may create either BIOS (UEFI-CSM) or UEFI(gpt) flash drives which only boot in one mode or other, even though Ubuntu ISO is for booting in either boot mode. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off.